# How to change price, the price calculation in cart through custom module Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, module, cart, price

Here 
in my custom module:

[image]

This product with **50 quantities price is 6,000**

But when I add to  cart this multiplies

So how I can fix this?

[image]

Can I use observer to change this or are there any other best way?
Thanks

```
 if ($quoteId != 0 && ($priceOne!=$item->getCustomPrice() || $quoteQty!=$item->getQty())) {
                $flag = 1;
                $item->setCustomPrice($priceOne);
                $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($priceOne);
                $item->setQty($quoteQty);
                //$item->setRowTotal($priceOne * $quoteQty);
                $item->setRowTotal($priceOne * 1);
                $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
                if ($helper->checkAndUpdateForDiscount($item)) {
                    $item->setNoDiscount(1);
                } else {
                    $item->setNoDiscount(0);
                }
                $item->save();
                $this->_messageManager->addNotice(
                    __(
                        "You can't edit quote items"
                    )
                );
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not understanding what is trying to be achieved.  What is the price for a single unit?  Are you trying to provide a tier pricing structure that has discounts for bulk purchases?

Comment: hi i want to send price to cart

Comment: but we are giving quantities is 50s  price  6,000

when add to cart it's multiplying we not need this for this module only

Comment: I'm still not understanding what is trying to be achieved. What is the price for a single unit, 10 units, 100 units? Seem like you're trying to use the qty field incorrectly and might be able to configure the product catalog to achieve goals without custom code. For example, use an attribute to show the number of units in a package. 
 That said, I've used the event sales_quote_product_add_after to add custom pricing logic when an item is added to cart.

Comment: i will explain.

Comment: i given 50 quantities  price is 6,000

Comment: per quantity is price is 120

Comment: i'm giving price for all quantities  


i need to take this price to cart with out quantity  multiply

Comment: are you understand

Comment: this module is setting for all the quantities price

Answer (score 0):

I still think you probably want to set price to $120 and then control available qty's via the frontend.  Then you might want to enforce qty's allowed in cart via a quote observer/interceptor.

To provide you an answer to the question of how to manipulate price for products in the cart a method I've used before is to observe the sales_quote_product_add_after event.  Below is a basic idea of the concept:

Company/Module/etc/events.xml

```
<event name="sales_quote_product_add_after">
    <observer name="company_module_quote_product_add_after"
              instance="Company/Module/Observer/QuoteProductAddAfterObserver" />
</event>
```

Company/Module/Observer/QuoteProductAddAfterObserver.php

```
...
class QuoteProductAddAfterObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
...
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $items = $observer->getEvent()->getData('items');
        foreach ($items as $quoteItem) {
           //...custom logic to items in cart...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but also quantities  not show as 1

Comment: The answer provides a way to "How to change price, the price calculation in cart through custom module Magento 2?"

Comment: can i get price and divided by the total number of quantities

Comment: i added code.............

Comment: The event provides access to an array of \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item.  If the provided information is not enough to get you working toward a solution you might want to consider looking for a third-party extension to meet your needs.

Comment: $item->setRowTotal($priceOne * 1);

i changed this line but not working